# Reduce or filter DC spike and noise

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, noise, oscillation, spike

Goodmorning,
I have a small voltage drop (about 20-25 mV, DC) on a sense resistor (0.180 Ohm) and I need to amplify this with an op-amp to reach 2-3 V (DC). The signal is not clean and the noise, with spikes, amplified generates oscillations making the circuit not working properly.
[image: Spike and noise]
[image: Spike and noise2]

How can I reduce or filter the spikes and have a more linear signal?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First single-trial ... sense resistor with a paralleled capacitor (something as 100nF -> 1 uF ?). Followed by R-C filter.

Comment: How fast is your (useful) signal changing? Can you tolerate a huge filter wich averages e.g. 1s of the waveform?

Comment: This signal, after amplification, must be compared (continuously) with a V ref by LM393 comparator and in case it will be greater the source is interrupted. The spikes amplified disturbs the circuit and false trigger the comparator. A circuit that filter and averages the waveform could be a solution, but I do not know how to build it

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing so already, you can use an instrumentation amplifier to buffer the signal from the sensor. Instrumentation amplifiers are low-noise and have a high CMRR. Also, determine the bandwidth of the signal that you wish to capture and design a corresponding low-pass filter. If the spikes are due to RFI then an RFI filter can be added as well.